# What's the default value of "inet" and "cidr" type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip, mac-address

When I execute the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "xxx" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ip" inet NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "mac_address" macaddr NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "status" varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

It reports an error:

```
execute error: pq: invalid input syntax for type macaddr: ""
```

So what's the default value of "inet" and "cidr" type in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why NOT NULL combined with an empty string as default value?

Comment: Only *you* know what's the default value supposed to be, there's no default DEFAULT

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to go with `NULL` values, instead of some default.

But, you can put in your own values if you follow the specified formats:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "xxx" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ip" inet NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0'::inet,
    "mac_address" macaddr NOT NULL DEFAULT '00-00-00-00-00-000'::macaddr,
    "status" varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

Comment: NULL is better than empty string.

Comment: @hunknownz you mean `NULL` string? that is not inet or macaddr format so wont work